# How to update magento 2.0.2 to 2.1.0 with composer?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

In magento 2.0.5 i tried update new version with.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

When i run line `composer update` get problem
[image]

this file composer.json

`"name": "magento/magento2ce",
 "description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
 "type": "project",
 "version": "2.0.2",
...
"require": { ...
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.0"
...`

Comment: Can you update your title?  It doesn't make sense.  Also, can you post the version of composer you have.  The error mentions you need ```1.0.0-beta1```

Comment: i updated with `composer self-update` now vertion 1.2.0  then i re-run get sample error.

Comment: Windows or Unix/Linux?  Also your title I think you mean 2.1.0.

Comment: I use Windows  sorry exactly 2.1.0

Comment: try looking in your .composer/config.json in the root of your Magento project.  Also, can you edit your post to include your composer.json enclosed in the code block?

Comment: i edited my question.

Comment: Can I see more of the ```"require"``` portion.  It has ... on it.  Should it not look similar to this?  ```"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.0",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magepal/magento2-googletagmanager": "^1.0"
    },
```

Comment: `"composer/composer": "1.0.0-alpha10",  "magento/composer": "~1.0.0",`

Comment: I wonder if these conflict.  Have you tried without one of these?  Say for example you could do without "magento/composer" and try?  I would keep this one as a backup before you do this though.  Also when you try and do ```composer update``` and make this change you have removed the hidden cache folder in the hidden composer directory of the root project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42741/discussion-between-camdixon-and-xanka).

Comment: you have to just changes in your composer.json file, you have to modify composer json with your new version and run composer update

Comment: please tell me What i need change? @Rakesh

Comment: Follow this instructions: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-rc1-samp.html I had the same problem and solved it!

Comment: @barnutius I don't have installed optional sample data

Answer (score 1):

Only changes are inside `composer.json` file,

Replace `"version": "2.0.2", to "version": "2.1.0"`, at line no.5
and Replace `"magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.2",` with **"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.0",** at line no 17.

Now run command,

```
composer update
```

all required changes are automatically downloaded using composer inside your magento folder.

After successfully upgrade from magento  2.0.2 to 2.1.0 you need to run command,

**Remove var folder and Remove pub/static  folder all content**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Thank you answer my question. After change i run `composer update` error like image in my question.

Comment: How can i solve the issue : warning : PHP Startup : oAuth  : unable to initialize module in wamp localhost

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in your Magento 2 root directory to upgarde your Magento 2.0.2 to 2.1.0

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the following commands to update my instance :

```
composer require "magento/product-community-edition:2.1.0" --no-update
composer update
```

Then you have to clean cache, run setup and redeploy static content :

```
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

BR,

Comment: In my question has show error when i follow this code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try cloning again the repo: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1 2.1 branch and then composer update